# Purrr with [[<-

Tags: r, purrr

Can someone explain to me why this gives an error using purrr:

```
map(list(list(a=1, b=2, c=3), list(a=1, b=2, c=3)), `[[<-`, "b", 1)
```

but the same call with lapply seems to work.

I was under the impression that `[[<-` was just a function call, so was expecting both purrr and lapply to do the same thing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue lies in `purrr::as_mapper()`, which `map()` calls under the hood. Consider the difference:

```
x <- list( a=1, b=2, c=3 )

`[[<-`( x, "b", 1 )                    # This is what lapply() calls
                                       # x is unchanged, returns modified list


purrr::as_mapper(`[[<-`)( x, "b", 1 )  # This is what map() calls
                                       # x is modified in-place, returns value 1
```

The second function call behaves as if you typed the following assignment expression:

```
(x[["b"]] <- 1)          
# [1] 1
```

which must be causing issues when the function is passed down to `map()` internals. Interestingly, wrapping the function with a `~` lambda works, but returns the "wrong" result:

```
y <- list(list(a=1, b=2, c=3), list(a=1, b=2, c=3))

purrr::map( y, ~purrr::as_mapper(`[[<-`)(.x, "b", 1) )
# [[1]]
# [1] 1

# [[2]]
# [1] 1

purrr::map( y, purrr::as_mapper(`[[<-`), "b", 1 )
# Error in list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)[["b"]] <- 1 : 
#   target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

The proper `purrr` equivalents to your `lapply()` example would instead look something like this:

```
r1 <- lapply(y, `[[<-`, "b", 1)
r2 <- purrr::map(y, purrr::modify_at, "b", ~1)
r3 <- purrr::map(y, ~`[[<-`(.x, "b", 1))

identical( r1, r2 )               # TRUE
identical( r1, r3 )               # TRUE
```

In the above, `modify_at()` returns the modified list, just like `[[<-(...)` does, and the tilde `~` is needed because `modify_at()` expects a function. The alternative is to wrap `` `[[<-` `` into a `~` lambda.